# Two inputs into ReduxForm field

Tags: redux, radio-button, redux-form

I have a `ReduxForm` and there I have a component that consists of two different types of inputs: a radio button group and a number text field. Is there a way to store in `ReduxForm` `Field` two parameters: value of the checked radio button and the value of the text field? How it should be organized using `format`, `normalize` properties and `onChange` function? Currently I have something like (simplified):

```
export const ComplexField = (props) =>
const { onChange, ... } = props
return(<div>
  <RadioGroup onChange=... />
  <InputTextField onChange=...>
</div>)
```

Basically the main issue that I have is data flow from two fields into the `ReduxForm` `Field`. I tried supplying `format` into the field config json like that:

```
format: (radioVal, inputVal) => [radioVal, inputVal]
```

I thought that maybe `onChange` would be different, but it seems not the case. `onChange` is just getting all the properties of the component currently interacted with (radio button group `OR` input text field but not both which I need).

The behavior that I am trying to achieve is the following: I have 4 radio buttons and the last one is connected to a number type text field. When I select the last radio button, text field is enabled and the user is allowed to enter the value. And the problem is that I can't just separate two components into two different `Fields` due to very strict `html` layout positioning. Is there a way to interact with two components under one `ReduxForm` field correctly or it is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue in the following way. First specify the `format` parameter and what to return at the very beginning when the value is `null`:

```
format: val => val || ['pli_0', null]
```

Here it can be seen that I am using the array for the value that `redux` store writes out. Then, the `onChange` method in the radio button group component:

```
onChange={({ checked }) => {
    if (checked) {
      onChange([option.value, option.inputVal])
    }   
}}
```

And input text field:

```
onChange={(val) => {
  onChange([value[0], val])
}}
```

Individual `onChange` methods get different values, because radio buttons and input field are two different form fields. But then the `component` in which they are included gets what I specify - the array of values.